# Disable a single consumer for a Queue from ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I have a queue with several consumers and I'd like to disable one from ActiveMQ.

I've looked into using JMX but haven't been able to see anything that would allow me to do this.

Ideally this would be without changing any of the code at the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveMQMessageConsumer` has no operations exposed via JMX to stop the process. The available options are:

1. Stop the consumer via the `ActiveMQMessageConsumer.stop` method or just kill the process.
2. Stop the ActiveMQ connection via the `ActiveMQConnection.stop` method. However, this is a heavy-handed measure because other JMS clients could be using sessions created from the connection.

Bruce